# how to replace string from one span to another in notepad++ with regex

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have something like that:

```
<span class="fl">abcd</span><span class="fr">efgh</span>
```

what i want is to get:

```
<span class="fl">efgh</span><span class="fr">abcd</span>
```

soo i want replace string from one span to another. Is there way to do it with notepad++?

Comment: Swapping values in programming language works like this => var a = "text" var b="other text", set var c = a, set a = b, set b=c. So you always need a third variable. Considering this, i'd dare to say it's fairly impossible to do this in notepad++. Another option that might be easier would be: change all fl to fr1 change all fr to fl change all fr1 to fr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=span class=\"...>)[^\<\r\n]+?(?=</span)
```

Horrible method but it works for your example string in Notepad++. The positive look behind and look ahead do not take into account all valid HTML. Needs refinement.